# Makefile ${if ... , ...} syntax

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Found syntax like this in some Makefile

```
${if ${VERBOSE},-DVERBOSE=true} ${if $G,-G "$G"}
```

I can guess what it does but cant find documentation.
Can someone point me to proper name/docs for this?

Comment: See ["Functions for Conditionals"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions).

Comment: Also see the name index in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited following correct observation that I wasn't pointing to the exact correct location.

Conditionals usually use the ifeq/ifneq/ifdef/ifndef directives (or if function as it turns out is the case). See Conditional Parts of Makefiles, Section 7 for directives or Section 8.4 for the if function in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Taken directly from there:

```
$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])
```

> The if function provides support for conditional expansion in a
>   functional context (as opposed to the GNU make makefile conditionals
>   such as ifeq (see Syntax of Conditionals).
>
> The first argument, condition, first has all preceding and trailing
>   whitespace stripped, then is expanded. If it expands to any non-empty
>   string, then the condition is considered to be true. If it expands to
>   an empty string, the condition is considered to be false.

Comment: The OP is asking about the `if` function, not the directives you describe here.

Comment: I suppose you are right now that I reread the OP - should have been more specific. In any case, my pointer to the documentation is correct - Conditionals start in Section 7 of the manual.

The if function is in Section 8.4 : 
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html


`$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])`